# Write to google sheet through javascript API not working with Google Identity Services

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using a Google sheet API and I can read just fine from the Google sheet, but I can't write to it. From what I read, I needed to use Google Identity Services to login so I tried integrating it, but I still can't get it to write to the sheet. I'm fairly sure I have everything setup correctly on console.cloud.google.com. Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>
<pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
<form id="violationForm">
    <h3>Detention Report</h3>
    <label for="duration">Select Duration:</label>
    <select id="duration" name="duration">
        <option value="15">15 minutes</option>
        <option value="30">30 minutes</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>

    <label>Reasons for Report:</label>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="tardy" name="reason" value="tardy">
            <label for="followDirections">Tardy</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="reason" value="Other">
            <label for="other">Other:</label>
            <input type="text" id="otherDescription" name="otherDescription" placeholder="Describe other reason">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="submitDetention" name="submitDetention" value="Submit Detention">
</form>

<script>
const CLIENT_ID = 'the client ID';
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
const discoveryUrl = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4';
const redirectUri = 'https://thewebsiteImusing.com/callback';
const API_KEY = 'theAPIKey';
const SHEET_ID = 'theSheetID';
let tokenClient;
let gapiInited = false;
let gisInited = false;
var detentionStudents = []

////////////Authentication and Google API Specific Code///////////////
function gapiLoaded() {
    gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
}
async function initializeGapiClient() {
    await gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: [discoveryUrl],
        scope: SCOPES,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    });
    gapiInited = true;
}

function gisLoaded() {
    tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        callback: '', // defined later
    });
    gisInited = true;
}

function handleAuthClick() {
    tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
        if (resp.error !== undefined) {
            throw (resp);
        }
        document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
        console.log('User signed in:', resp);
        // Continue with your logic after sign-in
    };

    if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
        // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
        // when establishing a new session.
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' });
    } else {
        // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: '' });
    }
}

function handleSignoutClick() {
    const token = gapi.client.getToken();
    if (token !== null) {
        google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
        gapi.client.setToken('');
        document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
        document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

function fetchStudentIDs() {
// Define the name of the sheet
const sheetName = 'studentList';

// Clear the detentionStudents array if it's not empty
detentionStudents.length = 0;

// Load the Google Sheets API
gapi.load('client', initClient);

function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        discoveryDocs: 
['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
    }).then(function () {
        // Fetch the data from the sheet
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
            spreadsheetId: SHEET_ID,
            range: `${sheetName}!A:A`,
        }).then(function (response) {
            const values = response.result.values;
            if (values && values.length > 0) {
                // Extract user IDs and store them in the detentionStudents array
                detentionStudents = values.map(row => row[0]);
                console.log('Student IDs retrieved:', detentionStudents);
                confirm('Student IDs retrieved:' + detentionStudents)
            } else {
                console.log('No data found in the sheet.');
            }
        }, function (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data from the sheet:', error);
        });
    });
}
}



function submitDetentionRecord() {
    const rowData = ["John Doe", "today", "30", "tardy", "1st Period"];

    // Append values to the "detentionRecords" sheet
    appendValues(SHEET_ID, 'detentionRecords', 'RAW', [rowData], (response) => {
        console.log('Detention record submitted to Google Sheet:', response);
        // Optionally, you can clear the form or perform other actions after submission.
        alert(`The detention for ${currentStudent} was submitted`);
    });
}

function appendValues(spreadsheetId, range, valueInputOption, _values, callback) {
    let values = _values;
    const body = {
        values: values,
    };
    try {
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
            spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
            range: range,
            valueInputOption: valueInputOption,
            resource: body,
        }).then((response) => {
            const result = response.result;
            console.log(`${result.updates.updatedCells} cells appended.`);
            if (callback) callback(response);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error appending values to Google Sheet:', err);
        alert('There was an error submitting the detention');
    }
}

// Attach the submitDetentionRecord function to the submit button

 
 
 
 document.getElementById('submitDetention').addEventListener('click', submitDetentionRecord);

</script>


<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide your current error message?

Comment: This is the console
Uncaught {error: 'idpiframe_initialization_failed', details: 'You have created a new client application that use…i/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information.'}
details: "You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that are deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."
error
: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"
[[Prototype]]: 
Object

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your question, you say `I'm using a google sheet API and I can read just fine from the google sheet, but I can't write to it.`. From your reply, when the values are retrieved from Spreadsheet using Sheets API with your showing script, no error occurs and the values are correctly retrieved. But, when the values are put to Spreadsheet using Sheets API with your showing script, the error in your reply occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the details of the difference between the worked script and the not worked script? Because, in your showing script, it seems that the script for retrieving values from Spreadsheet is not included.

Comment: Edit: I added the code for fetching the data from the spreadsheet. From what I've read, reading doesn't require using Google Identity Services but writing does. And I'm getting a login token but it's still not letting me write and I can't figure out why, and none of the code snippets or examples show a full writing version with the two working together.

Comment: And yes, your undestanding is correct. I'm able to retrieve the data and then display it in a table on the app.